# a python code to load next portion of data on memory while processing

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm running a CNN on my GPU and each time I load a portion of my dataset to an array as an input to my network. But after each time my process on that portion is finished the GPU must be idle for another portion to be loaded from disk.
I need a code like this :

```
thread1: #loading the data
   array1=load_data_portion(filename,next_portion)
thread2: #process on gpu
   if thread 1 is finished:
      array2 = array1
      run thread1 #(load next portion as my current portion in being processed)
      process array2
```

Comment: what is your question? And what library do you use to interact with your gpu?

Comment: I need a code to load the next portion of my data from disk on memory while the current portion is being processed. I'm using Keras with Tensorflow backend which trains my network on gpu.